# Naming conventions when defining "foreign key" elements in rest api body

Tags: rest, api, naming-conventions, naming

I am finally starting to realize Martin Fowler when he said there are only two things in computer science. One of those two things is **naming things**.

So half way trough creating json rest API, I noticed that I cannot get a consistent terminology in rest api.

For example, you can define country in many different ways. You could use country name, country iso two-letter code, country iso-three letter code, official name etc.

So instead of having

```
{
"country" : "FR"
}
```

would it be better to have

```
{
"country_iso_2" : "FR"
}
```

My reasoning is that when you use

```
{
"country" : ....
}
```

This could be name, iso two-letter code, iso three-leter code, numeric value, official name etc. One would have to check API documentation in order to see what is represented by "country".

Of course this is not a problem when it is a part of a country object such as

```
{
"country_id" : 250,
"country_name": "France",
"country_iso_2": "FR"
.......
}
```

but rather when you stumble upon it as a "foreign key" if I can call it like that, such as

```
{
"client_id": 3434343,
"country": "250"
}
```

So my question is for foreign key values, should I use general name such as "country" or should I be very specific what kind of information am I providing for  that element?